What are some green flags that tell a post doc supervisor is good?
I want to know whether I am in a good position or not: that is if my supervisor is good. Aside from their h-index and their "friends", practically speaking when doing some work with a postdoc, how to tell if the PI is a competent and a good people manager?
Is there some behavioral styles that could tell this?

Ask his current and previous students and postdocs. But preferred behavioral styles vary from person to person.

I'm somewhat surprised I've been unable to find a similar question asked before. However, We have a corresponding question about Ph.D. advisors, and I think there are many parallels in the answers if adapted to the postdoc stage (e.g., replacing "learning style" by "working style", and points about graduation by ones about placement in jobs of interest to you).

To those who are casting close votes: That's fair, but I don't see how we can close this question while simultaneously leaving the question @Anyon has linked open consistently. I'm of the mind that these are valuable and we ought to give at least a chance for answers to be curated effectively before jumping to close it.

I don't understand the reason for the close-votes at all, and it would be a courtesy to the original poster to suggest ways to improve it.

This seems to be asking for an unbounded list of "it depends" that aren’t even exclusive to academia - whether there are "behavioral styles that could tell" "if the PI is a competent and a good people manager" is as much personal preference as generic.

Voting to keep open, for the reasons given in this answer: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5395/8394
It was discussed on Meta years ago that "opinion-based" is (and should be) somewhat softer on academia.se than on many sites, because good questions on this site often do not have clear right or wrong answers.

I think it would be best if the question is edited to focus more on the academic aspects of a "good" supervisor, not "behavioral styles," whatever that is.

Ask them about their management style! When I met the PI who was interested in hiring me for a research assistant position, I asked him about how often he likes to meet, if he wants his employees to work set hours, and what his goals for the project were. We were aligned on how often we liked to have check-in meetings and the amount of flexibility there was in working hours, and he had clear goals for the project he was hiring me for. I also spoke to a colleague who had worked with him and said he was a good guy to work with.
If I was interviewing for a longer term position (this was only 4 months), I'd also ask about career development. Will there be time to work on fellowship applications? Do postdocs in his lab have opportunities to present their work at conferences? "My long term goal is X, will there be opportunities to work towards that in this position?"

The best indicator is success of former postdocs. Did they get jobs? Where? This is far from the only indicator but it is in my opinion, the best one.
Of course postdocs can do well in spite of a bad mentor or vice versa. Or they can do well but have a miserable experience etc. But a postdoc mentor with a track record of successful postdocs is a very good sign and a track record of unsuccessful postdocs is a very bad sign.

I don’t understand why you claim this is a very good sign after citing two strong reasons why this isn’t necessarily a good sign. This stack is riddled with questions lamenting a horrible experience with successful-people-producing professor X.

This is not true to much extent. I know a lot of colleagues to know that there is no such relation between the quality of postdoc mentor and where the postdocs land in their life.
